# Show Only Pings (Pingbacks+Trackbacks) Number on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, count, comments, trackback, pingback

Is there a way to display just ping counts (number) on Wordpress?

Actually there are [`comments_number`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/comments_number) function but that showing total count of comments, pingbacks and trackbacks.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works on WordPress 2.9.1. It may work on other versions, but I only tested it against 2.9.1.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$total_ping_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(comment_id) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_type = 'pingback'");
$total_approved_pings = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(comment_id) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_type = 'pingback' and comment_approved = 1");
$post_ping_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(comment_id) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_type = 'pingback' and comment_approved = 1 and comment_post_id = $post_id");
echo "The total number of pings on this site is $total_ping_count.\n";
echo "The total number of approved pings on this site is $total_approved_pings.\n";
echo "The total number of approved pings on this post is $post_ping_count.\n";
?>
```

The above code gives counts just for pingbacks. If you want trackbacks instead of pingbacks simply change `comment_type = 'pingback'` to `comment_type = 'trackback'` or if you want a combined count change it to `comment_type IN ('pingback', 'trackback')`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want: only show pingbacks? If so, and I haven't tried it, but [Template Tags/wp list comments « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_comments) shows listing pingbacks and options.